# Media queries for iPhone 14 (Pro, Max)

Tags: jquery, css

What are the CSS media queries to target Apple's latest devices?

2022 - Iphone 14 (Pro, Pro Max)

Comment: Does this help? https://www.webmobilefirst.com/en/devices/apple-iphone-14-pro-2022/

Comment: Iphone 14 max here https://www.webmobilefirst.com/en/devices/apple-iphone-14-max-2022/

Comment: I strongly suggest that you do not a address specific device until you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For Iphone 14 Pro**:
390 pixels width
844 pixels height (aprox.)

```
 @media only screen 
    and (device-width: 390px) 
    and (device-height: 844px) 
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { }
```

**Iphone Pro 14 MAX**:
428 pixels width
926 pixels height

```
 @media only screen 
        and (device-width: 428px) 
        and (device-height: 926px) 
        and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { }
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually experienced that the iPhone 14 Pro Max Vieport is even 430px wide. So better adjust up to that or even higher

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This line of code can help you to have an harmony in your responsive design :

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`